# sql server Cast X,000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this type of thing;

```
FORMAT(ISNULL([number],0),'#,0.00')
```

Which is showing me numbers like `3,567.00` but it is converting it Nvarchar can you guys help me which of this type is doing Numbers like  =>> 3,567.00 this : Float ?,Real?, Decimal? or witch one

Comment: A number doesn't have a format. Only the *display of* that number has a format.

Comment: Why you do that? Like @Hans said there's no format for a number, FORMAT function is useful just for reporting. Use proper data types and let your application decide how this should be formatted.

Comment: so i need in database numbers be like 3,567.00 and how i make it?

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are just numbers.

The number three thousand, five hundred and sixty seven is `3567` and nothing else.  If you want to store this number as a number in your database, it has to be stored in this manner, potentially with some decimal value.

Displaying that number is a different matter, which involves including non-numeric characters like commas.  When *presenting* this number with commas there is no issue as you are not saving it in that format.  If you try to *save* that number with formatting that included non-numeric characters, by definition you cannot do so in a purely numeric data type because a comma is not a number.

In short, store your numbers as numbers and format them *only* when you need to present them in a report of some description.